# Can screen rumbling/shaking be turned off in Smash Bros Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

The game looks great, and I will most likely buy it anyways, but can the screen be held steady? I was watching some 8 player mode action and when the screen is zoomed out and always shaking it looks awful. Can someone check the options? I feel like the game would be so much easier on the eyes and it would be easier to track your character if the screen rumbled less frequently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been many requests in previous smash games about the screen shake as well. No such option was given then, and no such option is available now.

Answer (score 0):

While not available for more than 4 players, the **Special Smash** mode in the Wii U version allows you to set the camera to "Fixed", preventing it from zooming.